# Is there a certain strategy for defeating Saddler?

Tags: resident-evil-4-2005

As you know, he is the hardest boss to kill in the game. I don't really have an employed winning strategy. Any suggestions?

Comment: I consider Saddler as one of the easiest bosses, the fight runs somewhat on autopilot.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I played Resident Evil 4, so I consulted a few game guide's for the boss sequence.

**When Saddler attacks** you can press dodge to avoid the attack, or prompt a quick time event to avoid the attack.

**Hit Saddler with explosives.** This seems to work the best. Grenade launchers or the RPG will work best. There ar explosive barrels around you can lure Saddler near to set off.

**Shoot Saddler's leg eyes.** These are the weak spots for shooting Saddler with guns.

**When Saddler is stunned** you can run up to him for a quick time event that deals extra damage.

**When Saddler's health is low** Ada will throw you an RPG. Make the shot count, but hit Saddler once with it and it will be all over.

[Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CI36-bgDmmU)